# Imprimir campo de un array en Angular

Tags: array, ionic, typescript, angular

Tengo una funcion en Angular que trae un array con los datos de usuarios, entre los cuales un campo es user.tipo_identidad_id, y tengo otra funcion donde traigo los tipos de identidades, como puedo comparar y segun el user.tipo_identidad_id imprima el campo tipo_identidad.name en HTML

`user = [{id: 25, tipo_identidad_id: 1, identidad: 2121212}]`

```
tipo_identidad= [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "DNI"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Pasaporte"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "RUC"
  }]
```

`<h3>Tipo de Identidad:</h3><b>{{tipo_identidad.name}}</b>`

Comment: intentastes `{{tipo_identidad.name | json }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer con la función "find()" en tu array de tipo_identidad. Te dejo un ejemplo en Angular.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class App {
  name:string;
  user[] = [{id: 25, tipo_identidad_id: 1, identidad: 2121212}];
  tipo_identidad[] = [
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "DNI"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Pasaporte"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "RUC"
  }];

  constructor() {
    var item = this.tipo_identidad.find(x=>x.id == 
    this.user[0].tipo_identidad_id);
    this.name = item.name;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a los datos de un [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) puedes acceder por la posición del array y el atributo que te interesa. Por ejemplo:

```
var user = [{id: 25, tipo_identidad_id: 1, identidad: 2121212}];

var tipo_identidad= [ { "id": 1, "name": "DNI" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Pasaporte" }, { "id": 3, "name": "RUC" }];

var tipoIdentidad = user[0].tipo_identidad_id;

var nombreIdentidad = getNameIdentidad(tipoIdentidad);

console.log(nombreIdentidad);

function getNameIdentidad(tipoIdentidad){
    for(var i = 0; i < tipo_identidad.length; i++){
        if(tipo_identidad[i].id == tipoIdentidad){
            return tipo_identidad[i].name;
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

En la variable **tipoIdentidad** tienes el valor que te interesa. De aquí ya puedes insertarlo en el HTML.

```js
var user = [{id: 25, tipo_identidad_id: 1, identidad: 2121212}];

var tipo_identidad= [ { "id": 1, "name": "DNI" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Pasaporte" }, { "id": 3, "name": "RUC" }];

var tipoIdentidad = user[0].tipo_identidad_id;

var nombreIdentidad = getNameIdentidad(tipoIdentidad);

console.log(nombreIdentidad);

function getNameIdentidad(tipoIdentidad){
    for(var i = 0; i < tipo_identidad.length; i++){
        if(tipo_identidad[i].id == tipoIdentidad){
            return tipo_identidad[i].name;
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```